# Periodically call a method from controller and display updated returned data without reload

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a web application project in which I need to display some data on a view which should periodically update itself.

I have a method in Admin controller:

```
public int Ntcou()
        {
            return repObj.repnoti();
        }
```

here *repObj.repnoti()* returns integer number.

I have a view that has a div within which the number returned by **Ntcou** should be displayed and also I want it to refresh itself after every 2 seconds.
Please help with the possible jQuery code that can call **Ntcou** method from controller periodically and display updated returned data by that method without reloading the page and display the number within that division.

Comment: What have you tried to refresh yet? Can you share your view code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming html such as:

```
<span id="valueGoesHere"></span>
```

You can use `setTimeout` with a function, such as:

```
var updateValue = function() {
    $.get( "/Ntcou", function( val ) {
      $( "#valueGoesHere").html(val);
    });
};

setTimeout(updateValue, 2000);
```